# Solving the system $w_1+w_3 = 1$, $ -5w_1 + w_2 + 5w_3 = -25$, $-25w_1 + 8w_2 + 25w_3 = -250/3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

We have

\begin{align} w_1+w_3 &= 5, \tag1 \\ -55w_1 + w_2 + 35w_3 &= -235, \tag2 \\ -6w_1 + 3w_2 + 26w_3 &= -2 \tag3 \end{align}

To me this seems impossible to solve... Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I tried manipulating this in various ways however I can't get the solution... Manipulating the second equation yield that $w_2 = -25$, but then in the third equation this doesn't make sense, because we have 8$w_2$ and the whole equation is only equal to $-250/3$...

Comment: 83.333, so yes. @Yuki.F

Comment: @Moo, thanks dude!

Answer (score 1):

The determinant is nonzero, so we have the unique solution $x=A^{-1}b$ to $Ax=b$, which is
$$
(w_1,w_2,w_3)=(79/18,125/9,-61/18).
$$
Here I assumed that $-83.333...=-250/3$.